внедрение heygen в телеграм
Друзья всем привет! Хотел бы узнать возможно ли внедрить API HeyGen AI в телеграмм бота, а то в интернете такой информации нет. Похоже еще никто не делал этого.

Ну если есть апи, то можно, конечно.

Ты даже не попробовал, можно кончено
